# Unable to locate UI element using Xpath?

Tags: selenium

I am trying to  locate UI lement using selenium , but Xpath is dynamically changing evrytime 
Here is the source

```
<div id="tab-1080" class="x-tab x-box-item x-tab-default x-top x-tab-top x-tab-default-     top x-noicon x-tab-noicon x-tab-default-noicon x-active x-tab-active x-tab-default-active x-top-active x-tab-top-active x-tab-default-top-active" style="margin: 0px; left: 406px; top: 0px;">
<em id="tab-1080-btnWrap" class="">
<button id="tab-1080-btnEl" class="x-tab-center" autocomplete="off" role="button"  hidefocus="true" type="button">
<span id="tab-1080-btnInnerEl" class="x-tab-inner" style="">Report Center</span>
<span id="tab-1080-btnIconEl" class="x-tab-icon x-hide-display"> </span>
</button>
</em>
</div>
```

I need to locate this uniquely but the id 1080 keeps changing evreytime ? Can anyone help how to locate with span id "Report Center" as that's the only attribute to differentiate this button in my webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
//span[text()='Report Center']
```

Comment: When i give Xpath="//span[text()='Report Center']" scripts works first time , but when i re -reun the same script again its not working for my application

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use css: they're faster than xpath and generally accepted as superior by the community, I also think they're easier to use as well provided you do some research.

http://sauceio.com/index.php/2010/01/selenium-totw-css-selectors-in-selenium-demystified/

```
span.x-tab-inner ==> finds the element by its class
span[id*=btnInnerEl]` ==> finds element by a partial piece (substring) of the id
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways; I can suggest these ones (come into my mind at the time):

1. `"//span[contains(text(), 'Report Center')]"`
2. `"//span[contains(@id, 'btnInnerEl')]"`
3. `"//span[contains(text(), 'Report Center') and contains(@id, 'btnInnerEl')]"`